# New examples of Slidify with Shiny app widgets?

Tags: r, shiny, interactive, slidify

I'm getting tired of seeing the same Shiny Quiz example embedded in Slidify presentations over the Internet. Isn't there a **simple index.Rmd file** where you can clearly see how the shiny `ui.R` and `server.R` codes are embedded in a Slidify presentation **using widgets** and loading some data ?

I need to see how you add to Slidify a classic `ui.R` with widgets

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( *widgets here* )
    mainPanel( *output from interactive render functions* )
  )
))
```

and a `server.R` loading some data and with corresponding `renderX` functions

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$out1 <- renderText({ ...})
...
}
```

Thank you in advance for your support !

Comment: I got mixed up with my last "answer" (deleted) "_adding_ `runtime: shiny` _in the YAML header, no need to add {r opts.label = 'shiny'} in the chunk_". It has nothing to do with Slidify ...